# Google CloudBuild artifacts YAML

Tags: google-cloud-build

I've followed the docs for Google CloudBuild here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts

So here's my `cloudbuild.yaml` configuration:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
id: git-checkout
args: [ 'fetch','--tags','--unshallow']
- name: openjdk
id: gradle-build
args: [
    './gradlew',
    '--build-cache',
    '-Si',
    '-Panalytics.buildId=$BUILD_ID',
    '-PgithubToken=$_GITHUB_TOKEN',
    '-g', '$_GRADLE_CACHE',
    'build'
]
artifacts:
objects:
    location: ['gs://my-bucket/artifacts/']
    paths: ["build/libs/*.jar"]
```

If I comment out, the following, then it runs successfully:

```
artifacts:
objects:
    location: ['gs://my-bucket/artifacts/']
    paths: ["build/libs/*.jar"]
```

Without comments, I get the following error from the CloudBuild console:

`failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string`

And under the *Logs* section, it simply says *Logs unavailable*.

Comment: Ever figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objects.location` element should not be an array.

The following should work:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://my-bucket/artifacts/'
    paths: ["build/libs/*.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to indent `objects:` line

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: ['gs://my-bucket/artifacts/']
    paths: ["build/libs/*.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this error with a section of my cloudbuild.yaml file looking like:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args:
  - clone 
  - -depth
  - 1
  - --single-branch
  - -b
  - development
  - git@bitbucket.org:aoaoeuoaeuoeaueu/oaeueoaueoauoaeuo.git
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
```

Seems the issue is with the `1`. So I just added quotes around which fixed it (`- "1"`).